# Using display equations in inline lists with enumitem

Tags: lists, enumitem

I am trying to create in-line lists in LaTeX, and this works wonderfully well using the `enumitem` package.

But if I want to place a displayed equation (which would not be often for inline lists... but I need to sometimes) an error is generated.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}                

\newlist{enumerateIL}{enumerate*}{1}%         
% Inline enumeration environment

\setlist[enumerateIL,1]{font=\itshape\bfseries,label={\arabic*.}} 
% Format itemize \item's  


\begin{document}

An in-line list:
\begin{enumerateIL}
   \item
   The first point:
   $a + b = c$.

   \item
   The second point
   \[a^2 + b^2 = c^2.\]

\end{enumerateIL}

\end{document}
```

I get this compilation error

```
:
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.21    \[a^
            2 + b^2 = c^2.\]
```

As suggested by the error message, in line equations work OK... but not displayed equations.

Is there a way of making this work with `enumitem`?  If not, is there an alternative for me to look at?

Thanks.

P.

Comment: How do you want these to be handled? In my opinion, you should just use `$\displaystyle ...$` instead of `\[ ... \]`.

Comment: Use the option `mode=unboxed`.

Comment: @JavierBezos Can you provide an answer, please?

Answer (score 2):

Answer due to the comment by @JavierBezos changing the mode to `unboxed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
text before inline itemize environment
\begin{enumerate*}[mode=unboxed]
  \item this is an inline itemize environment with math environment
    \begin{equation}
      E= mc^2
   \end{equation}
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also make this a global default using `\setlist[itemize]{mode=unboxed}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here I use manual linebreaks with extra space `\\[5pt]` to set off the equation, and use `$\displaystyle...$`to set the equation in a full-width text box.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}                

\newlist{enumerateIL}{enumerate*}{1}%         
% Inline enumeration environment

\setlist[enumerateIL,1]{font=\itshape\bfseries,label={\arabic*.}} 
% Format itemize \item's  

\begin{document}

An in-line list:
\begin{enumerateIL}
   \item
   The first point:
   $a + b = c$.

   \item
   The second point\\[5pt]   
   \makebox[\linewidth]{$\displaystyle \frac{x}{a^2} + b^2 = c^2.$}\\[5pt]
   More stuff
   \item
   More stuff More stuff More stuff More stuff More stuff More stuff
   More stuff More stuff More stuff More stuff More stuff More stuff
   More stuff More stuff More stuff More stuff

\end{enumerateIL}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This can be automated with the following preamble addition:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{enumILeqn}{\\[5pt]\makebox[\linewidth]{$\displaystyle\BODY$}\\[5pt]}
```

and usage as

```
The second point

\begin{enumILeqn}  
\frac{x}{a^2} + b^2 = c^2
\end{enumILeqn}

More stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently getting around the issue using `$\displaystyle...$` but, of course, that keeps the maths inline and does not generate a centred, displayed equation which I am hoping for.  I sometime have quite complicated equations I wish to use, for which `$\displaystyle...` sometimes isn't good enough.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).