# Problem with inline version of enumitem package

Tags: align, enumitem

The following document doesn't compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
      \begin{enumerate*}[label=\alph*)]
        \item We have 
        \begin{align*}
        \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}&=
        \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2^2-x^2}}
        \end{align*}
      \end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

However, if I comment out the commands corresponding to enumitem like this,

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
    \begin{document}
    %     \begin{enumerate*}[label=\alph*)]
    %       \item We have 
            \begin{align*}
            \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}&=
            \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2^2-x^2}}
            \end{align*}
    %     \end{enumerate*}
    \end{document}
```

it compiles without any problem.
What can be the problem? 
I am using texlive 2018. Here is what I get if I type 
pdflatex --version

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
Copyright 2018 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.00
```

There has been no updates to enumitem after 2011, so I suppose I have the latest version of the package.

Comment: It seems as if you want an inline list (`enumerate*`) but then want that to include an `align*` which is a display mode environment.  Either use `enumerate` with `align`, or if you really want to use `enumerate*` then use `$\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}$`.

Comment: How would you want a display environment to be displayed in an inline list?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `aligned` instead of `align*` in an inline list:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
      \begin{enumerate*}[label=\alph*)]
        \item We have 
        $\begin{aligned}[t]
        \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}&= \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2^2-x^2}} \\
        \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}&= \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2^2-x^2}} 
        \end{aligned}$
      \end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Related: [Using display equations in inline lists with enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333017/using-display-equations-in-inline-lists-with-enumitem) . It was a bad choice from my part making `mode=boxed` the default mode, instead of `mode=unboxed`.

So, just set the mode to `unboxed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate*}[mode=unboxed,label=\alph*)]
    \item We have 
    \begin{align*}
    \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}&=
    \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2^2-x^2}}
    \end{align*}
  \end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot mix inline list with display mat. replace `enumerate*` with `\enumerate`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
     \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
       \item We have
        \begin{align*}
        \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}&=
        \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2^2-x^2}}
        \end{align*}
     \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and you will obtain:

[image]

(note: use `align` here has no sense, `equation` or `gather` will give after removing ampersand the same result.)

or use in-line equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
     \begin{enumerate*}[label=\alph*)]
       \item We have $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2^2-x^2}}$
     \end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

and result will become:

[image]

Comment: Thanks everybody ! Stupid of me to mix inline enumitem with align*. It is fixed.