# Patching a math command using regexpatch

Tags: xetex, patching, xpatch

I want to allow my inline math to break lines after `\sim`, which I'm using a lot. To this end, I've tried:

```latex
\usepackage{regexpatch}
...
\xapptocmd{\sim}{\allowbreak}{SUCCESS}{FAIL}
...
$X \sim N(0, 1)$
```

Unfortunately this just prints out `FAIL` at the top of the document, but I'm not sure how to diagnose why `\xapptocmd` is actually failing. Is it possible to patch math commands in this way?

I'm happy to swap `regexpatch` out with any other package if it helps.

Comment: The reason involves quite some low-level TeX details... but there's `\let\oldsim\sim \def\sim{\oldsim \allowbreak}`

Comment: \sim is not a command, it is a \mathchar.

Comment: `\sim` is not defined with `\def` or similar instruction, so it cannot be patched this way. By the way, line breaks are allowed after relation symbols, which `\sim` is.

Comment: Please add value to your question by adding relevant code, starting with documentclass (copy&run).

Comment: Probably duplicate of [math mode - automatic \allowbreak around mathbin and mathrel characters - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81879/automatic-allowbreak-around-mathbin-and-mathrel-characters). (or not? Not sure)

Comment: beside this: breaking after \sim is already allowed, it works fine for me.

Comment: For inline math I don't think anything breaks automatically?

Comment: @Migwell No line break is possible if you use `\sim` inside `\left`-`\right` pairs, for instance. But generally a break after `\sim` *is* allowed.

Comment: Right, well then I need to diagnose why my document is not breaking at anything.

Comment: Okay it turns out I wasn't getting any equation breaking due to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362034/169711. Happy to close or post this as an answer as appropriate.